# OnListItemClick is not getting invoked when I call ViewPager.setPageTransformer

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have an activity that contains ViewPager to display different fragments when swipe.

Each fragment has a ListView in it, and each list view item perform some action when get clicked (let say shows Toast). I set OnItemClickListener on ListView to achieve it.

Everything works fine, But when I set page transform by calling setPageTransform() on ViewPager then list item click stops working.

How can I fix it?

Check the code below.

list_item_lessons.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="16dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_image"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    tools:src="@drawable/people"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        tools:text="ਐਤਵਾਰ"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_sub_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:textColor="#757575"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="alphabets" />


</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:src="@drawable/general_arrow_right"
    android:alpha=".5"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

Code that set page transformer inside MainActivity.java

```
// Set transformation for view pager, Getting values from preferences
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String displayPref = sharedPref.getString(SettingsFragment.KEY_PREF_TRANSFORMATION, "");
viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, Utils.getPageTransformer(this, displayPref));
```